# What insect is this? I spotted it on a wall in a bedroom

Tags: species-identification, entomology, pest-control

[image: Closed up insect 1]
[image: Cropped image]

This is the closest distance & the best photo resolution I could get from my handphone.

I discovered it on a wall in my bedroom.

1. Could anyone identify what insect is it?
2. Why the insect is in the bedroom?
3. How do I prevent this insect from staying in the house?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Identifications questions should include: 1) one or more clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible); 2) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; and 3) an estimate of the size of the organism. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information after checking to see whether a similar question has already been answered. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site.

Comment: "Why [is] the insect... in the bedroom?" sounds a lot like "Why did the chicken cross the road?"